# How to run a conditional in Jenkins to fail based on output from a previous stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is a basic construct I built to present my question.

```
stage('Run pre-checks') {
    steps {
        //Run pre-check scripts
    }
}
stage('Deploy config ') {
    when {
       expression {
        //Insert expression here
       }
    }
    steps {
        //Run a script
    }
}
```

Based on the construct below, what I am trying to do is to run a specific script only when a specific output from the “run pre-checks” script is displayed on the stdout of that stage, which will be a python script. If the pre-check shows this output, you will skip the second step rather than running it. Would anyone know the environment variable(s) and/or Methods that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sh command can return a value instead of printing it.

```
MY_OUTPUT = sh (
    script: '... your command....',
    returnStdout: true
)
```

Then you can do whatever you want with MY_OUTPUT (trim(), substr...)

The current link to the documentation is here ([Sh shell script](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script)) :

> **returnStdout (optional)**
>
> If checked, standard output from the task is returned as the step value as a String, rather than being printed to the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the log.) You will often want to call .trim() on the result to strip off a trailing newline.
>
> Type: boolean